# I am using the current version of xcode, but I want my iphone app to work on an iPhone 3g (iOS v4).

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am using the current version of xcode, but I want my iphone app to work on an iPhone 3g (iOS v4). How can i ensure I will have no compatibility issues?

Under xcode preferences, in Downloads, I can't even see anything older than iOS 6.0 simulator. How can I get the older versions?

Comment: You can't, the latest SDK do not have support for the ARMv6 any more. This you can not compile any app that will run on the iPhone 3G any more.

Comment: Also, you can't support anything older than iOS 4.3 and the iPhone 3G only goes to 4.2.1.

Comment: If you want to support your own iPhone 3G then download and install Xcode 3. You can't use this for the App Store